# Android Studio crashes on startup, but not on v1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

(Windows) The latest Android Studio when executed, briefly shows its loading screen and then disappears without an error. 1.4.1 does this as well, however 1.0.2 does not. I've only tried those 3 versions. I've tried re-downloading and re-installing it multiple times. Yet only the older version works.

I want to use the newest version because of all the things it brings, but also because theres compatibility issues with 1.0.2 and the latest libraries or something. I'd rather fix the problem with the latest version rather than with this version.

Any help or ideas?

EDIT: I have tried running as admin. 
My comp is 64bit and I am executing the 64bit version. The 32bit version gives an error complaining about using the wrong version and then quits.

Comment: Are you running Android Studio as an administrator? I know that not doing so can cause lots of trouble on Windows.

Comment: Yes. I tried that as well.